# How to calculate the margin of error for a different survey sampling unit?

Tags: confidence-interval, survey, survey-sampling

Assume a margin of error of 5% based on a sample of x households (the sampling unit of a survey), what would be the margin of error for y individuals (y = x*z and z is the average household size)?

Answer (score 1):

The standard error, the basis of the margin of error is not computable that way. The se depends on both the sample size and the intraclass correlation among members of the same household and on any other design components such as stratification and probabilities of selection.

Comment: So there is no way to calculate the margin of error or the confidence interval for statistics based on individuals rather than households (since the sample was designed with households as the sampling unit), right?
Would be fair to assume that the margin of error will be higher for individuals?

Comment: The se (and the margin of error based on it) for individuals can be calculated. It can't be calculated the way you suggest. Software suitable for survey analysis can compute a se for individuals. This is often done for surveys, many of which use selection of households and then selection of individuals within households. Whether a se is higher or lower for individuals depends on characteristics of both the design and the items measured and no one knows, in general, if the se is higher or lower.

Comment: Thanks again. I guess that wasn't clear in my question -  the survey use selection of households and then survey all individuals in the selected household. I understand if we were to design the survey to sample individuals or individuals within households, then we can calculate the se for individuals' statistics but was curious if we can approximately calculate the se for individuals based on household sampling (or assume it'd be higher or lower). If I understand your comment correctly, the answer should be no. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No. Use standard survey analysis methods for individuals.